# HELP Identifying a vintage MTB frame

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage, road

I only have three clues:

1. "3.0 Aluminum" on the top tube
2. Serial Number on the frame itself
3. "Designed in the USA" flag decal

Can anyone help me identify this vintage MTB frame?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell, No replaceable derailleur hanger means is likely low quality or possibly custom build.

Comment: "Designed in USA" means it was made elsewhere, otherwise it would say "made in USA"  So there's an excellent chance this is from the far east.  Doesn't mean its bad, just means its impossible to identify.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="3.0+aluminium"+bicycle suggests there's a Huffy with a similar name, and a GT Avalanche, and a "teman" plus other names.  Have a go at the images and see if you can hit a match

Comment: Possibly Cannondale. The font looks familiar and the “designed in USA” means it’ll be a mass production frame out of Taiwan. “3.0 Aluminium” is a cannondale branding of their flavour of aluminium alloy.

Answer (score 0):

measure head tube size 1.5 inches probably gary fisher AL3

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  What year and model would that be?

Comment: Why would a 1.5 inch head tube size (diameter I have to assume) indicate a Gary Fischer?  This is really more of a comment on the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58574)